# RichTextBox lifetime in static method context

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Please take a look at the method depicted below

```
        public static string RemoveRTF(string input)
        {
            string output = input;

            RichTextBox RichTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
            try {
                RichTextBox1.Rtf = input;
                output = RichTextBox1.Text;
            } catch (ArgumentException argExp) { 
                /*
                 * The supplied input value is not in RTF format. 
                 * Ignore.
                 */
            }
            return output;
        }
```

My question is, will the above code when called several times generate a large amount of USER Objects, Handles Or GDI Objects.

The reason for asking is that I have some code which worked perfectly one day and then the next day without any code changes made stopped working with the reported error :
Error creating Window Handle..

Only thing is that I cant seem to see the cause for the problem except that the callstack shows me that the error originates in the above code.

TaskManager do not reveal a large amount of USER objects or such being created, so I really do not know what is going on.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that code?

Comment: why not lift the RichtTextBox outside this method (as a static field)? This will remove much of the overhead, but I doubt that this is the problem if you really didn't change a thing and now got the problems.

Answer (score 3):

You should dispose your `RichTextBox` to free up any unmanaged resources.

```
RichTextBox1.Dispose();
```

Comment: the `try`-`catch` is there for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

or you can make one global `RichTextBox` and use it.

```
    RichTextBox RichTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
    public static string RemoveRTF(string input)
            {

    string output = input;

    try {
                    RichTextBox1.Rtf = input;
                    output = RichTextBox1.Text;
RichTextBox1.rtf = null;
                } catch (ArgumentException argExp) { 
                    /*
                     * The supplied input value is not in RTF format. 
                     * Ignore.
                     */
                }
                return output;
            }
```

or use using()

Answer (score 0):

The RichTextBox object only works on the UI thread. Calling this code from the background thread will throw an Exception with a message like "Error creating Window Handle.."

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" UI thread.  Perhaps you're thinking of the restrictions on accessing GUI components from threads other than the thread in which the component was created?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said UI environments pumping windows messages e.g. not console applications or services.

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same error that u r facing "Error creating window handle". This issue occurs because even if we create object of RichTextBox and and set that object to null at the end of the method, it does not get disposed and so initially it works fine and then later on it start giving "error creating window handle". So instead use "Using". It will dispose object of richTextBox outside "using" context. This will solve that error.

private String RemoveRtf(String RtfScript)
        {
            string PlainText = null;

```
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(RtfScript))
            {

                using (RichTextBox richTxtBox = new RichTextBox())
                {


                    richTxtBox.Rtf = RtfScript;

                    PlainText = richTxtBox.Text;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log error here
        }
        finally
        {
            RtfScript = null;

        }
        return PlainText;
    }
```